# Published feature service with massive features drawing too slowly

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service

I have published a feature class with a massive number of polygons with large vertices on ArcGIS Online. When opened and viewed in Map Viewer, it drew acceptably slowly.

I noticed it was hosted published as a Feature Service. I opened the Developer tool on the web browser. Every zoom in/out and pan triggered a massive data (10MB plus) transfered from the FeatuerServer on ArcGIS Online. What was returned was a large collection of feature geometry. That's why it took ages to draw on the map.

I am wondering if the hosted feature class can be published as Map Service or WMS so that the data transfered could be simply images like what is returned by a "export" capability for a MapServer.

By the way this hosted feature layer woule be updated quite often, e.g. twice a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish as a tiled service, which is almost the same as a WMS.  When you publish the service from ArcMap, Under 'Capabilities' select 'Tiled Mapping' instead of 'Feature Access'.  Tiled mapping publishes like a WMS and Feature Access publishes like a WFS:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I have also had the Time-Enabled capability on the feature layer. This capability was lost when published as Tiled Mapping Service. How to fix this?

Comment: Ask another question on this site :).  I don't know the answer but someone might.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish hosted tile layers from hosted feature layers and have the tiles automatically update and because this has a linked feature layer the popups can be displayed.

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/07/06/creating-tiles-from-features-efficient-automatic-and-economical/